# Pass Array of JavaScript objects to PageMethod

Tags: asp.net, javascript, pagemethods

Here's the situation: I would like to iterate through a table with input controls, collect up the values and then submit them to an ASP.NET `PageMethod` to save the data to the database. I have the collection all figured out but am getting an error that the string can't be converted to a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

So I end up with something like this being passed to a method with the below signature

```
[
{ 'id': '383840923', 'name': 'fred', 'car':'honda' },
{ 'id': '243', 'name': 'joe', 'car':'honda' },
{ 'id': '4323423', 'name': 'paul', 'car':'honda' },
{ 'id': '38384234230923', 'name': 'ted', 'car':'honda' },
]

public static bool SaveData(Dictionary<string, object>[] items) {...}
```

I know that I can pass whole class objects back and forth if properly declared and ASP.NET will handle the conversions for me, but I don't need the whole class being passed, only a couple of the properties.

Edit: I'm using jQuery to do the post back to the server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I was wrapping the array in quotes before sending it in as part of the `$.ajax` call so it was being treated as a string instead of an array.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Request.Path) %>/UpdateAcademicItems",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'items': **'**" + $.toJSON(items) + "**'**}",
    success: function(data) {
        if(false != data.d) {
            alert('we did it');
        } else {
            alert ('flop');
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Failed to save Program Items');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET AJAX will automatically deserialize that for you if you use a DTO](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).  Something like this on the server-side would match the JSON array you're sending in:

```
public class PeopleAndCarsDTO
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string car { get; set; }
}

public static bool SaveData(List<PeopleAndCarsDTO> items) {...}
```

Comment: Yea, I think I've read most of your blog more than once today. Great help. That's what I was trying to avoid having to create, but I figured out what the problem was. I was wrapping the array in quotes before it was being posted so it was being treated as a string instead of an array. So I can get away with my custom array.

Answer (score 0):

@Jared the passed object is a JSON array. You can use [**json sharp**](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to process it on server side. [**Here**](http://www.nateirwin.net/2008/11/20/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet/) is a nice post about converting json array to C#.