# Problem with passing object to server with jQuery.Ajax()

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement the same code that was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871709/pass-array-of-javascript-objects-to-pagemethod/871748)

Currently I have the following code:

```
var pagePath = window.location.pathname;

var paramList = '';
if (paramArray.length > 0) {
 for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i ++) {
  if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
  paramList += "{'id':'" + paramArray[i].id + "', 
                       'collapsed':'" + paramArray[i].collapsed + "', 
                       'order':'" + paramArray[i].order + "', 
                       'column':'" + paramArray[i].column + "'}";
 }
}
paramList = '[' + paramList + ']';

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
//Call the page method  
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: pagePath + "/" + fn,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 data: "{'items': **'**" + $.toJSON(paramList) + "**'**}",
```

dataType: "json",
 success: successFn,
 error: errorFn
 });

I am trying to pass this data to the WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static String SaveData(Dictionary<String, Object>[] items)
```

The problem is that I keep receiving the error "500 Internal Server Error".
I'm pretty sure that the data type is causing the problem but just can't figure it out.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have a look in e.g. firebug what your post data looks like? The Asterixes within the JSON string look a little bit strange to me.

Comment: I think you don't need to serialize the paramList, you already did it. now you are just sending a string. see my answer. I think you will have success if the parameters match the pagemethod

Comment: yeah used firebug and my post data looks like this:

"[
{'id':'1', 'collapsed':'0', 'order':'0', 'column':'column2'},{'id':'2', 'collapsed':'1', 'order':'1', 'column':'column2'},{'id':'3', 'collapsed':'0', 'order':'0', 'column':'column3'}
]"

Comment: you want your paramList string to look similar to this var postData = '{input: { Name: "Foo", Age: 21 }}'; Notice param names not quoted, integer not quoted, and if there was a bool, it would not be quoted.  See listing 6 and 7 in the article I linked under my answer.  You are almost there.

Comment: now what does the pagemethod signature look like?

Comment: PageMethod signature is shown in my initial post:

[WebMethod]
public static String SaveData(Dictionary<String, Object>[] items)

Comment: ok, you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: ok, now what does your post data look like? all of it. the previous one you showed was missing it's items wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your service decorated with [ScriptService] attribute?

and what's up with the asterisks? is this some new macro i didn't get the memo on?

```
"{'items': **'**" + $.toJSON(paramList) + "**'**}"
```

try

<strike>"{'items': " + $.toJSON(paramList) + "}"</strike>

As i see it, you are already creating json. no need for the toJSON

try replacing the single quotes with double quotes. e.g.

```
'{"items": ' + paramList + '}'
```

your post data should look like this

```
'{
    "items": [{
        "id": "1",
        "collapsed": "0",
        "order": "0",
        "column": "column2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "collapsed": "1",
        "order": "1",
        "column": "column2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "collapsed": "0",
        "order": "0",
        "column": "column3"
    }]
}'
```

inline

```
'{ "items": [{ "id": "1", "collapsed": "0", "order": "0", "column": "column2" }, { "id": "2", "collapsed": "1", "order": "1", "column": "column2" }, { "id": "3", "collapsed": "0", "order": "0", "column": "column3" }]}'



var paramList = "";
if (paramArray.length > 0) {
 for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i ++) {
  if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ",";
  paramList += '{"id":"' + paramArray[i].id + '", 
                       "collapsed":"' + paramArray[i].collapsed + '", 
                       "order":"' + paramArray[i].order + '", 
                       "column":"' + paramArray[i].column + '"}';
 }
}
paramList = "[" + paramList + "]";

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
//Call the page method  
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: pagePath + '/' + fn,
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 data: '{"items":' + paramList + '}',  // the rest of your function is missing
```

Comment: No, I am not using [ScriptService] as I am using a Page Method and not a Service.

Got the asterisks from the link I posted... changed it to your suggestion but am still receiving error 500 :(

Comment: what is the method signature on the pagemethod?

Comment: as background on how parameters are dealt with, you can see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38999/Consuming-ASP-net-WebServices-WCF-Services-and-sta.aspx

Comment: did all the changes you suggested and still getting the same error